# JAXB, setting namespace to all child elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class such as the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "a")
public class ClassA {
    @XmlElement(name = "b", namespace = "http://mynamespace.com")
    private ClassB;
}
```

This would result in the following XML:

```
<ns2:a>
    <ns2:b>
        <c/>
    </ns2:b>
</ns2:a>
```

`ClassB` and all of its attribute classes are in a separate library not written by me. How can I force those child classes to use the namespace that I've given to `ClassB`? Like this:

```
<ns2:a>
    <ns2:b>
        <ns2:c/>
    </ns2:b>
</ns2:a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe to put [XmlSchema](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) annotation into package with class B

Comment: But `ClassB` is in an external library? Or do you suggest to create a dummy package with the same name, and put XmlSchema annotation on it?

Comment: I can't suggest, beacuse haven't tried it myself. But yes, I think this can help.

Comment: +1 - For more information on JAXB and namespaces see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html